# Swift animated circular progress bar

Tags: swift, animation, progress

I have created a circular progress bar in Swift that animated over 1.5 seconds to value 1 when user hold on view. But I want to add a new viewcontroller when animation is done and restart my circular progressbar if user ended to early. Can someone help me?

Circulars progress bar is working with animation when user hold on view and stop at release.

```
class CounterView: UIView {
    var bgPath: UIBezierPath!
    var shapeLayer: CAShapeLayer!
    var progressLayer: CAShapeLayer!


    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        bgPath = UIBezierPath()
        self.simpleShape()
    }

    required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        bgPath = UIBezierPath()
        self.simpleShape()
    }

    func simpleShape()
    {
        createCirclePath()
        shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.path = bgPath.cgPath
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 5
        shapeLayer.fillColor = nil
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor

        progressLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        progressLayer.path = bgPath.cgPath
        progressLayer.lineCap = kCALineCapRound
        progressLayer.lineWidth = 5
        progressLayer.fillColor = nil
        progressLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.yellow.cgColor
        progressLayer.strokeEnd = 0.0


        self.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
        self.layer.addSublayer(progressLayer)
    }

    private func createCirclePath()
    {

        let x = self.frame.width/2
        let y = self.frame.height/2
        let center = CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
        print(x,y,center)
        bgPath.addArc(withCenter: center, radius: x/CGFloat(2), startAngle: CGFloat(0), endAngle: CGFloat(6.28), clockwise: true)
        bgPath.close()
    }

    var animationCompletedCallback: ((_ isAnimationCompleted: Bool) -> Void)?

    func setProgressWithAnimation(duration: TimeInterval, value: Float)  {

        CATransaction.setCompletionBlock {
            if let callBack = self.animationCompletedCallback { callBack(true) }

        }

        CATransaction.begin()
        let  animation = CABasicAnimation (keyPath: "strokeEnd")
        animation.duration = duration
        animation.fromValue = 0
        animation.toValue = value
        animation.repeatCount = 1
        animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction (name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear)
        progressLayer.strokeEnd = CGFloat(value)
        progressLayer.add(animation, forKey: "animateprogress")

        CATransaction.commit()
}

    func removeLayers() {
        shapeLayer.removeAllAnimations()
        shapeLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()
        progressLayer.removeAllAnimations()
        progressLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()
    }





}





             class ViewController: UIViewController {


                    @IBOutlet weak var counterView: CounterView!
                    @IBOutlet weak var holdView: UIView!
                    var isAnimationCompleted = false             


                    override func viewDidLoad() {
                        super.viewDidLoad()
                        addLongPressGesture()
                       addCounterViewCallback()


                    }    
             @objc func longPress(gesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
        if gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.began {
       // self.counterView.simpleShape()
        self.counterView.setProgressWithAnimation(duration: 1.5, value: 1.0)

        }
        if gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.ended {
            if !isAnimationCompleted {
                self.counterView.removeLayers()
            }
        }
    }


    func addLongPressGesture(){
        let lpgr = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(longPress(gesture:)))
        lpgr.minimumPressDuration = 0
        self.holdView.addGestureRecognizer(lpgr)
    }

    private func addCounterViewCallback() {
        counterView.animationCompletedCallback = { [weak self] (isCompleted) in
            guard let weakSelf = self else {return}
            weakSelf.isAnimationCompleted = isCompleted
            weakSelf.addFlashView()
        }
    }


          func addFlashView(){
                        let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)

                        let resultViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ResultView") as! Flash

                        self.present(resultViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)
                    }
```

Add new viewcontroller when animation is done and restart animation if user release view and hold on it again.

Comment: "Add new viewcontroller when animation is done"  Que!?  Add a new view controller to what?

Answer (score 1):

Add a `callback` to know when animation is ended. And use `CATransaction` to know when animation is completed.

```
var animationCompletedCallback: (() -> Void)?
func setProgressWithAnimation(duration: TimeInterval, value: Float)  {

    CATransaction.setCompletionBlock {
        if let callBack = animationCompletedCallback {
            callBack()
        }
    }

    CATransaction.begin()


    let  animation = CABasicAnimation (keyPath: "strokeEnd")
    animation.duration = duration
    animation.fromValue = 0
    animation.toValue = value
    animation.repeatCount = .infinity
    animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction (name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear)
    progressLayer.strokeEnd = CGFloat(value)
    progressLayer.add(animation, forKey: "animateprogress")

    CATransaction.commit()
}
```

And add this function after `addLongPressGesture()` in `viewDidLoad()` :

```
private func addCounterViewCallback() {
    counterView.animationCompletedCallback = { [weak self] in
        guard let weakSelf = self else {return}
        weakSelf.addFlashView()
    }
}
```

To remove layer use this:

```
func removeLayers() {
   shapeLayer.removeAllAnimations()
   shapeLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()
   progressLayer.removeAllAnimations()
   progressLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()
}
```

**Update 1:**

To remove animation if user stops pressing, you need can add on variable in callback like this :

`var animationCompletedCallback: ((isAnimationCompleted: Bool) -> Void)?`

So now callback in `CounterView` will be :

`if let callBack = animationCompletedCallback { callBack(true) }`

In your controller add one variable: 
`var isAnimationCompleted = false`

Change `addCounterViewCallback()` :

```
private func addCounterViewCallback() {
    counterView.animationCompletedCallback = { [weak self] (isCompleted) in
        guard let weakSelf = self else {return}
        weakSelf.isAnimationCompleted = isCompleted
        weakSelf.addFlashView()
    }
}
```

Now you can add one condition in your longPress():

```
if gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.ended {
  if !isAnimationCompleted { 
      //Call remove layers code
  }
}
```

**Update 2:**

Add a variable in `CounterView`:

```
var isAnimationCompleted = true
```

Change callback like this :

```
CATransaction.setCompletionBlock {
    if let callBack = self.animationCompletedCallback { callBack(isAnimationCompleted) }
}
```

In controller `longPress()` :

```
if gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.ended {
   if !isAnimationCompleted {
      self.counterView.isAnimationCompleted = false
      self.counterView.removeLayers()
   }
}
```

Modify `addCounterViewCallback()` to this:

```
private func addCounterViewCallback() {
        counterView.animationCompletedCallback = { [weak self] (isCompleted) in
        guard let weakSelf = self else {return}
        weakSelf.isAnimationCompleted = isCompleted
        if isCompleted {
          weakSelf.addFlashView()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have add that to my code, but its error on callback. Its says callback:                
resolves to an unused function.

Comment: I have updated code, but error is still:                                                                               callBack resolves to unused function.

Comment: Is that error in this line : `if let callBack = animationCompletedCallback {
                callBack()
            }` then check the updated code.

Comment: That solved my problem, but my animation does not switch to Flash view when animation of circular progress view is done.

Comment: Does that function gets called after animation is finished? Try adding break point and see. Also test `addFlashView()` in viewWillAppear whether its working at all or not.

Comment: I have added break point to see if animation get done and addFlashView() gets call at viewWillAppear and at end state of hold down if I remove backslashes. Its also switch to Flash viewcontroller but not when animation is done. The problem now if I add addCounterViewCallback() to end state and remove addFlashview () its swtching to Flash viewcontroller if user release hold down at second time after animation is done at first time. I think my problem is at 
    func setProgressWithAnimation(duration: TimeInterval, value: Float) .

Comment: I am not able to understand what are you saying here. Do you have any github link for this task which you can share ?

Comment: I dont have an github link right now, but I have add images of main storyboard. The first viewcontroller is with two views. One thats called holdview that let user use longpress with began and end state and one view for Counterview which is my circular progress. My circular progressview should only animate when user hold on holdview and when thats done its should switch to Flashview.

Comment: You are calling `addCounterViewCallback()` from wrong place, call it after addLongPressGesture() in viewDidLoad().

Comment: I have called addCounterViewCallback()  now at viewDidLoad (), but now my animation is running to the end of my circular progress bar and then restart animation and when user hold at view after restart its switching to FlashView. I want my animation to stop when my circular progress bar is filled and then switch to FlashView.

Comment: remove this line from your animation code `animation.repeatCount = .infinity`.

Comment: Solved it by changing infinity to value 1.

Comment: Thanks for all help, I have one last problem and thats is how do I change my Circular progress bar to value 0 when user release view before animation is done?

Comment: You can remove layer from `superLayer`, if you don't want to animate back to value 0. and call `simpleShape()` before calling `self.counterView.setProgressWithAnimation(duration: 1.5, value: 1.0)` in `longPress()`.

Comment: I dont want it to animate back to zero so I have added removeLayers () now and that works. But where should I put removeLayers() if I want it after user ended longpress if addCounterViewCall is not done?

Comment: Check the Updated answer.

Comment: I have updated it, but I get an undeclared type isAnimationCompleted at          
 var animationCompletedCallback: ((isAnimationCompleted) -> Void)?

Comment: My bad, check the updated answer. I missed the data type there.

Comment: That solved my problem, but now its switching to Flashview when animation is done and if user ended Flashview before animation is done. How do I fix this?

Comment: Check the Update 2 modifications.

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem. But now my Circular progress bar cant start a new animation after user end before its done. I have already tried with self.counterView. createSimplePath() at began state but that didnt work. How to fix this?

Comment: Call simpleShape in began state.